# How to setup Openshift all-in-one cluster

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am new to openshift origin and just downloaded binary (All-in-One Server) from below URL and untar it

```
https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases
```

Now while google i found two option to start working with it, i want to know whats difference between them??

```
oc cluster up
openshift start
```

As both are providing console like

```
localhost:8443/console
```

Comment: What is the end goal? Are you just trying to setup a local instance you can use to experiment with or develop apps? If that is the goal, you are better off actually using Minishift. In general I would avoid ``openshift start`` for running local instance for this purpose. See free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ for suggested methods for running locally.

Comment: I am evaluating openshift for production deployments, thats why i choose all-in-one to start. Goal is to migrate existing Karaf based apps to cloud.